# MediaRecorder has a delay of multiple seconda

Tags: html5-video, media-source, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to use a MediaRecorder to record a MediaStream and display it in a video element using a MediaSource. So the setup looks like:

1. Request a MediaStream from the browser
2. Add it to the MediaRecorder
3. Add the recorded blobs to the MediaSource Buffer

The result looks very good but there is one problem: There is a delay in the playback.
When displaying the MediaStream directly there is no delay so I sorted out the first bulletpoint as the problem.
Nevertheless, it seems like either the MediaRecorder or the MediaSource is adding a delay of about 3 seconds to the stream.

```
this.screenRecording = await mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: { frameRate: 60, resizeMode: 'none' } });
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.screenRecording);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = async (event: any) => {
  if (this.screenReceiving.readyState === 'open') {
    if (this.screenReceivingBuffer == null) {
      this.screenReceivingBuffer = this.screenReceiving.addSourceBuffer('video/webm;codecs=vp8');
    }
    if (!this.screenReceivingBuffer.updating) {
      this.screenReceivingBuffer.appendBuffer(await new Response(event.data).arrayBuffer());
    }
  }
};
mediaRecorder.start(16);
```

The above code is only copy & paste from the actual project so please don't expect it to work by copy & paste ;)

Does anyone have an idea why this delay exists?
Any ideas on how to tweak the browser to not add this delay?

Comment: You can't not have a delay.  That's not physically possible.  There are various buffers all around to support the encoding, and then again for smooth playback.  You need to reset your expectations.  Why would you do this?  Why not just display the MediaStream directly?  Or if you're transmitting it somewhere, why aren't you using WebRTC?

Comment: I would like to build a custom encryption into the stream which is not possible for WebRTC is it? Nevertheless, I was expecting a delay but multiple seconds seem a little high for simple encoding decoding.

Comment: Why custom encryption?  WebRTC streams are encrypted already.

Comment: The stream is routed to multiple users via a server. The server should not be able to decrypt the stream. Is there a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Normally, WebRTC is peer-to-peer.  If you're going by way of your server to go to multiple users, you probably actually want the server to be able to decrypt the stream so it can be transcoded.  Otherwise, you're stuck with the same codec and bitrate as the original, which may not be compatible.

Comment: Due to the nature of the application there is no way we can allow the server to view the stream. The codec has to be transcoded on either end. Nevertheless, is there a way to add custom encryption to WebRTC or, better, reduce the delay for the MediaSource/Recorder?

Comment: It all depends then on what "multiple" is.  Are we talking thousands here?  Or, like 2?  Custom encryption isn't what you want, isn't feasible, and doesn't actually solve your problem.  MediaRecorder isn't designed for low latency, and nor should it be.  WebRTC is what you do want, and supports everything you're trying to do out of the box.  Your clients will just have to deal with a lowest-common-denominator quality of a stream which will be pass-through on your servers.  Or, if there are only a couple clients, send multiple streams from the encoder...

Comment: ... you'd have to send those multiple streams to the server anyway if you wanted that encoding done clientside.

Comment: So there is no "low latency" possible within the browser apart from using direct peer to peer?

Comment: Not quite.  There's no low latency video encoding aside from the WebRTC stack.  One of those "peers" can be the server, and that server can forward on streams.

Comment: @M.Schröder not sure if I totally understand your post but we might have a similar problem, by "delay" did you mean a delay in terms of the recorder itself (not including the network) that's the issue I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035109/html5-mediarecorder-capture-very-slow
Whereas the MediaRecorder API already have a delay in the recording itself alone, in my code I am not even transmitting to network just buffering the stream from the camera then using MediaRecorder to record that stream and display to another video element, delay is 5 secs already (no network involved)

Comment: Hey @xybrek that exactly our problem as well. We solved it by using the MediaStream API instead of the MediaRecorder API. Unsure if this might be an option for you too.

Comment: @M.Schröder it's basically the response of `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` right? How did you manage to get "chunks" or "slices" out of that stream? I mean like MediaRecorder API which has a callback that returns the sliced media, how did you do it with that MediaStream API?